# Want to setup magento on magento-cloud

Tags: magento2, magento2-enterprise, magento2-cloud

I want to setup Magento on Magento-Cloud. I have tried to set it up. But when I see at the directory, I can see all the Magento directory and the files listed there. But during setup of cloud I didn't get any information to install the database or create any database. So currently I am getting error when I tried to access front URL and the **error** is,

> " report.CRITICAL: MySQL adapter: Missing required configuration
>   option 'host' "

Also when I check the env.php file, just kind of below details are present, not even db connection codes.

```
<?php
return array (
  'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'compiled_config' => 1,
  ),
  'cron' => 
  array (
    'enabled' => 0,
  ),
);
```

Anybody knows what I forgot to set it up Magento on Magento-Cloud?

Answer (score 0):

For Magento cloud server we can move files only, so i suggest you to install fresh magento into your local server and move all files to cloud server.

Also upload that database to cloud database and just need to update base url from core_config_data table.

Comment: But where do I setup connection of DB for cloud? This is my actual doubt.

Comment: i think you need to ask to magento support for ssh and database details.

Comment: i have both details, so i have upload whole setup to cloud

Comment: I have ssh but not database details.During installation didn't get any conformation about the database. Similarly when I check at env.php and there is also not any database details mention.

Comment: Check your magento cloud account, from there you can get details or you need to ask to support team.